# What's principle of JPA annotation @Column ? Didn't call field's get method?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

How did it get field value? Isn't it through field's `get` method? when i user hibernate *.hbm.xml it always run field's `get` method to get value,but `@Column` is not.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rank")
public class Rank implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1673403567289141704L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "rank_key")
    private String key;//like 25_1508757477589

    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private Integer type;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date shareDate;//this field can't get value
```

// other field getter and setter

```
    public void setShareDate(Date shareDate) {
        this.shareDate = shareDate;
    }

    public Date getShareDate() { //get timestamp through key
        String[] split = key.split("_"); 
        Long time = Long.parseLong(split[1]);
        return new Date(time);
    }
}
```

When i use `Rank.hbm.xml`, the field `shareDate` can call `get` method get value(is will run `getShareDate` method) ,Did i miss something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="*.Rank" table="rank">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="userId" type="int" column="user_id"></property>
        <property name="key" type="string" column="rank_key"/>
        <property name="data" type="string" column="data" />
        <property name="type" type="int" column="type"></property>
        <property name="shareDate" type="java.util.Date" column="date"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of access: property access and field access.

**From Pro JPA2**:

> If you annotate fields, the JPA provider will get and set the fields
>   of the entity using **reflection**. If the annotations are set on the
>   getter methods of properties, those getter and setter methods will be
>   invoked by the provider to access and set the state.
>
> Annotating the fields of the entity will cause the provider to use
>   field access to get and set the state of the entity. Getter and setter
>   methods might or might not be present, but if they are present, they
>   are ignored by the provider.
>
> When property access mode is used, the same contract as for JavaBeans
>   applies, and there must be getter and setter methods for the
>   persistent properties.

Same case with hbm (hibernate mapping) XML. The property element has `access` attribute. The values of which can be **field** or **property**. If not defined, it defaults to **property**.

HBM will always override annotations.

So now, let us inspect your code.
You have put `@Column` annotations on your fields (not on the getter methods). From here, you are using **field access**. However, you also have a HBM xml file, and HBM uses property access by default, and it overrides annotations. So in the end, you are using **property access** (instead of field access). That is why the getter method is invoked to get the value. Otherwise if field access is used, value is captured through reflection.

If you're asking about what is the purpose of the `@Column` annotation. Read the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) documentation. It basically maps your entity field/property to a specific column in your physical table. This is optional, and if you don't declare it, default values will apply. See API for more info on default values.

Comment: @lsh,tks your repo,i means did JPA annotation '@Column' never call filed's 'get' method ?how did it get filed's value.reflect? what principle of '@Column'?

Comment: Thanks you again @lsh,There is a little to be sure, i;m not use '*.hbm.xml' and '@Column' in same time ;) I just think '@Colum' not through getter method to access attribute, so i change the 'Rank.class' as a simple pojo no JPA annotations,Through this problem i think I need to learn more,tks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all viewer, I have been able to get the 'shareDate' attribute values,I change all JPA annotations on getter function, it's works for me. But i really want to know how @Column get pojo field's value.

Comment: `@Column` doesn't "get" anything. It is an annotation. Inanimate. A persistence provider "gets" values.